# HTMLEntities decodes &nbsp; to ascii 194, shouldn't it be 160?

Tags: html, ruby, utf-8, jruby

I'm using HTMLEntities to decode HTML-Strings. Today I saw that &nbsp; is decoded to 194 instead of 160.

```
jruby-1.6.2 :002 > HTMLEntities.new.decode( "&nbsp;" )[0]
 => 194
```

Is 194 correct, or am I doing something wrong (maybe something with UTF-8-Strings in Ruby)?

(JRuby = 1.6.2, Rails = 2.3.11, HTMLEntities = 4.3.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is the first byte of a two-byte UTF-8 sequence.  Try unpacking it to see the expected Unicode code point:

```
HTMLEntities.new.decode( "&nbsp;" ).unpack('U*')[0]
```

Comment: Thank you! That explains everything!